# How to lock tables and figures to a specific position in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'd like to lock a group of images, tables, and text to a specific location in Word, so that regardless of additional pages or text added, the position of this group is fixed, as shown below.

[image: Illustration of fixed group of images, tables and text in document]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can lock it to a position on a page but not a particular page. Say more about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @RichMichaels That would be an acceptable compromise. Yes, I would like to lock it to a position on any page, how can that be done?

Comment: @RichMichaels About what I'm trying to accomplish: When I type text above a group of items (including images, tables, text) on a page, I would like the text to continue below the group, rather than pushing the group down towards the end of any page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objective is to have text flow around an inserted image or table, then you need to apply a Wrapped Text attribute to the object.

For images, Right Click on the image to bring up the contextual control box. Hover over the Wrap Text menu item and you will see another menu. From it you can choose various options for wrapped text. However, with your added desire to maintain a fixed position on a page for the object, select the More Layout Options choice.

[image]

The dialog contains Text Wrapping choices, but it also includes a Position tab for aligning the image to particular positions on the page. Make sure you check the Lock Anchor box before you exit this dialog. Experiment with the various setting to get your image positioned where you want it to be.

You can do similar things with Tables, but accessing the layout options is a bit different.

Right click in the table and choose the Table Properties option. Then select the Wrapping text option you want and click the Position button to get to the options that are available for positioning.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I did (Table Properties) -> (Positioning) -> uncheck (Move with text), to lock a 1x1 table with hidden borders (which can contain any combination of images, tables, and text) to get the exact result I was looking for. 

I also tried the image lock method; while that worked, it also messed up the SVG-format image used to test it. So tables are good enough for this purpose.

Comment: And how do you keep its caption attached to the table? I followed these instructions, but the caption moves when I modify the text before the table.